# What does the question mark mean in the return statement in JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I've got a function service the using data from loader and transform it in the right way for me and then return new data
I have a suggestion to use '?' before returning data in transformation that can make some sense if there will not be data from loader:

```
export default async function serviceInputSearch(url) {
  const data = await new DataLoader(url).get();
  return data?.data.results;
}
```

I cannot find any information in google about this '?' in return statement?
What does it mean?

Comment: It's called [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Comment: It’s not particular to a `return` statement, it can be used in any expression that attempts to reference a member field of an object.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is called optional chaining. You can find more information about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining.

But, given your example, the gist of it is that the question mark validates if there is a valid "data" object. If you do not have the question mark there and there is no data object or it is null, then an error will be thrown in the lines of "Cannot read the property data of 'undefined'".

Answer (score 5):

This is called as **[Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)**

```
const adventurer = {
  name: 'Alice',
  cat: {
    name: 'Dinah'
  }
};

// you can use it to check if the property is exist in the object
const dogName = adventurer.dog?.name; //same as adventurer.dog && adventurer.dog.name ? adventurer.dog.name : undefined;
console.log(dogName); //undefined
```

or else you can use it for check/call the existence of function of inside a object

```
// if someNonExistentMethod is exists in the adventurer Object call it.
console.log(adventurer.someNonExistentMethod?.());
```

---

Syntax is

```
const adventurer = {
  name: 'Alice',
  cat: {
    name: 'Dinah'
  },
  skills: ['jump']
};

obj.val?.prop => //Optional chaining
    ex: adventurer.dog?.name

obj.val?.[expr] => //Optional chaining with expressions
    ex: const propertyName = 'name'; adventurer.dog?.[propertyName];

obj.arr?.[index] => //Array item access with optional chaining
    ex: adventurer.skills?.[0] //jump

obj.func?.(args) => //Optional chaining with function calls
    ex: adventurer.someNonExistentMethod?.()
```

Answer (score 5):

Its the "optional chainging" operator.

Here an use case:

```js
let obj = {};

console.log(obj?.person?.age);
console.log(obj.person.age);
```

It comes handy if you try to access an property that not there. Its `undefined` so you get the error `cannot get xx of undefined`

To prevent this error you put an `?.` infront of it, it will return an `undefined` back rather then throwing an error

Here some examples:

```js
let obj = {};


//method does not exist
console.log(obj.func?.())


let arr = ["tom"];
console.log(arr[2]?.name);


let matrix = [ [ 1 ], [ 2 ] ];
console.log(matrix[5]?.[3]);


let defaultName = obj?.name ?? "Tom";
console.log(defaultName);
```

Answer (score 3):

It is optional chaining operator.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Answer (score 0):

[reference](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/new-javascript-features-in-2019-optional-chaining-null-coalescing-a7fd38f4ef2d)

In Javascript, we would need to explicitly check every reference to make sure it’s defined. If we have a deeply nested reference within an object, it might look something like this:

```js
let networkFetchResult = await fetch("https://myfriends.com/user/123").then(res => res.json());
// Let's assume that the first friend of our request user is our best friend
let bestFriendsName = networkFetchResult
  && networkFetchResult.data
  && networkFetchResult.data.user
  && networkFetchResult.data.user.friends
  && networkFetchResult.data.user.friends[0]
  && networkFetchResult.data.user.friends[0].name
  || "You don't have any friends!";
```

Instead you can just do

```js
let networkFetchResult = await fetch("https://myfriends.com/user/123").then(res => res.json());
// Still assuming that our first friend is our best friend
let bestFriendsName = networkFetchResult?.data?.user?.friends?.[0]?.name || "You don't have any friends!";
```